# How to loop through elements using javascript on button click?

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I am trying to outline 3 boxes on a button click.
On next click outline would shift to the next box, this continues.
Tried using loop, present one is infinite loop.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#click');
    button.addEventListener('click', change);
    var test = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
    
        function change(e){
                var i = 0;
                while(1){
                    if(i == 2){
                        test[i].style.outline = '8px ridge rgba(170, 50, 220, .5)';
                        i = 0;
                        continue;
                    }
                    else{
                        test[i].style.outline = '8px ridge rgba(170, 50, 220, .5)';
                        i++;
                        
                    }
                }
        }
```

```html
<div class="container">
                <div class="grid">
                    <div class="test">test</div>
                    <div class="test">test</div>
                    <div class="test">test</div>
                </div>
                <button id="click">Click</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Hello Dipsankar Maity, Welcome to S.O. Do you want to continue iterating when `i == 2` ? if not, you need to use `break` to stop the loop.

Comment: `while (1) ` without any break statement, will run the loop indefinitely. `if(i == 2)`, what is the purpose of setting `i=0`?

Comment: `while (1) {` is forever

Comment: thanks everyone the suggestions helped, now i get  it that the script is always running & the click action here can be used instead of loops.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi just add a variable counter which would be incremented at each click and when then counter is equal to the number max of div It come back to 1.

like that

```
 <script>
    var button = document.querySelector('#click').addEventListener('click', onClick);
    var allDiv= document.querySelectorAll('.test');
    var count=0;
    function onClick(e){
        if (count >= allDiv.length){
            count = 0;
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < allDiv.length; i++) {
            allDiv[i].style.outline = '';
        }
        allDiv[count].style.outline = '8px ridge rgba(170, 50, 220, .5)';
        count = count + 1;
    }
</script>
```

It could be improve of course ...

Answer (score 1):

The reason your loop is infinite is because of `while(1)`. The number `1` is truthy, and it doesn't change, so the loop will run endlessly.

Here's an alternative that doesn't use a loop, but instead stores a `clickCount` variable in global scope:

```
const button = document.querySelector('#click');
button.addEventListener('click', change);
const test = [...document.querySelectorAll('.test')];

let clickCount = 0;

function change() {
  clickCount++;
  test[clickCount % 3].style.outline = '8px ridge rgba(170, 50, 220, .5)';
}
```

I you want the first click to trigger `test[0]`, you could use `let clickCount = -1` instead.

If you want the previously outlined element to lose it's outline, you could change the function to:

```
function change() {
  clickCount++;
  test[clickCount % 3].style.outline = '8px ridge rgba(170, 50, 220, .5)';
  test[(clickCount + 2) % 3].style.outline = 'none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextElementSibling` and `firstElementChild` properties of elements for this so you don't get stuck in an infinite loop and you don't need to use loops at all or track indexes. See my example in the snippet.

To make it easier to code a put your styling to a class which then is removed and added to the next element.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#click');
button.addEventListener('click', change);

function change(e) {
  var gridElement = document.querySelector('.grid');
  var outlinedElement = gridElement.querySelector('.outline');

  //remove current outline class if it exists
  if (outlinedElement) {
    outlinedElement.classList.remove('outline');
  }

  //Add it to the next element sibling or if it doesn't exists add it to the first child of grid.
  if (outlinedElement && outlinedElement.nextElementSibling) {
    outlinedElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add('outline');
  } else {
    gridElement.firstElementChild.classList.add('outline');
  }
}
```

```css
.outline {
  outline: 8px ridge rgba(170, 50, 220, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
  </div>
  <button id="click">Click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here away to do it make an active class and your counter i should be out of the function because in each click you shouldn't reset it to zero.

```js
var button = document.querySelector('#click');
button.addEventListener('click', change);
var test = document.querySelectorAll('.test');
 var i = 0;
function change(e) {
    var activeItem = document.querySelector('.active');
    if(activeItem) activeItem.classList.remove("active");
    
    if (i == test.length) {   
      i = 0;  
    }      
    test[i].classList.add("active");
    i++;
}
```

```css
.active{
  border: 8px ridge rgba(170, 50, 220, .5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
    <div class="test">test</div>
  </div>
  <button id="click">Click</button>
</div>
```